# Where to call join() when multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

When using multiprocessing in Python, I usually see examples where the `join()` function is called in a separate loop to where each process was actually created.

For example, this:

```
processes = []

for i in range(10):
    p = Process(target=my_func)
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()

for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

is more common than this:

```
processes = []

for i in range(10):
    p = Process(target=my_func)
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

But from my understanding of `join()`, it just tells the script not to exit until that process has finished. Therefore, it shouldn't matter when `join()` is called. So why is it usually called in a separate loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`join()` is blocking operation.

In first example you start 10 processes and then you are waiting for all procces to finish. **All processes are running at same time.**

In second example you start one process at time and you are waiting for finish before you start another process. **There is only one running process at same time**

First example:

```
def wait()
    time.sleep(1)

# You start 10 processes
for i in range(10):
    p = Process(target=wait)
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()

# One second after all processes can be finished you check them all and finish
for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

Execution time of whole script can be near **one second**.

Second example:

```
for i in range(10):
    p = Process(target=wait) # Here you start one process 
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()
    p.join() # Here you will have to wait one second before process finished.
```

Execution time of whole script can be near **10 seconds!**.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So in the first example, let's say all processes take roughly the same time to execute. The second loop will wait until the first process has finished, and then very quickly loop through all other 9 processes, almost instantaneously?

Comment: @Karnivaurus: right.  The processes will run in parallel, and your wait is only for the longest *one* process.  Your second solution will require waiting for each process in succession.

Comment: Keep in mind that many setups you'll get to run on do *not* have multiple processors for you, and will simply time-slice the ten processes.  Thus, you'll have a very similar effect to execution.